# How may I get more "credits" on my IBM Quantum Experience profile?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

[image]

How can I have 150 or more credits?
I mean I want to have '150/150 credits'.

Answer (score 2):

The point of the credits system is to make access to the devices fair so that everyone can take a turn at using them. You cannot get that number of credits as it would mean you could add a lot of jobs to the queue, slowing down response times for everyone else. I don't think there is any simple way to increase the number of credits you have.

I would suggest running jobs on the simulator if you need to run that many credits worth of jobs, as simulator jobs don't use up any credits.

Comment: thanks. I can now believe that not everyone can apply for a researcher account? Because it didn't seem difficult before。